# Is Noetherian required to conclude that radical of an ideal is a finite intersection of prime ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, proof-verification, noetherian

Consider the collection $C$ of all ideals $I$ of $R$ such that $\sqrt{I}$ is not a finite intersection of prime ideals. Now using Zorn's lemma $C$ has a maximal element and that won't be prime. Continuing it seems we can get that radical of any ideal $I$ is a finite intersection of prime ideals. Where is my mistake?

I have seen this result stated with Noetherian hypothesis, but the above indicated proof does not use that hypothesis.

Comment: How did you prove that $C$ is inductively ordered? And what do you mean by  "continuing"?

Comment: Ok, I assumed the existence of maximal element $I$ by Zorn's and then observe that it is not prime and choose $x,y\notin I$ with $xy\in I$. Then just show that $\sqrt{I}=\sqrt{I+x}\cap \sqrt{I+y}$ is a finite intersection of prime ideals to get a contradiction. But I guess I cannot apply Zorn's lemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is.

Let $R=K^{\mathbb N}$ be the ring of sequences with elements in a field $K$. Then $R$ is reduced, and [every prime ideal of $R$ is maximal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168084/prove-that-if-r-is-von-neumann-regular-and-p-a-prime-ideal-then-p-is-maxi). Now suppose that $(0)=\bigcap_{i=1}^nP_i$. Then, by [CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Statement_for_general_rings) we get that $R\simeq\prod_{i=1}^nR/P_i$, that is, $R$ is isomorphic to a finite direct product of fields, so $R$ is noetherian, a contradiction.