# Why is a non-zero-divisor a unit in zero dimensional ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring of Krull dimension $0$.

Let $x\in R\setminus\{0\}$ such that $x$ is non-zero-divisor. Then, how do I prove that $x$ is a unit?

Comment: Almost a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518/why-does-a-minimal-prime-ideal-consist-of-zerodivisors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of zero-divisors in a commutative ring is the union
$$\bigcup_{\mathfrak p\in\operatorname{Ass}_f(A)}\mathfrak p,$$
where $\operatorname{Ass}_f(A)$ denotes the set of *weakly associated* prime ideals in  $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$, and these sets are the same if $\dim A=0$.

Alternatively each non-zero divisor is a unit in each localisation $A_\mathfrak p$  since the maximal ideal of the latter is made up of nilpotent elements. Hence the image of a non-zero divisor in $\displaystyle\prod_{\mathfrak p\in\operatorname{Spec}(A)}\!\!\!\!A_\mathfrak p$ being a unit, is itself a unit by faithful flatness of $\displaystyle\prod_{\mathfrak p\in\operatorname{Spec}(A)}\!\!\!\!A_\mathfrak p$.

Answer (score 1):

It's [known that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2410455/29335) such rings have the property that every chain of the form $xR\supseteq x^2R\supseteq x^3R\supseteq\ldots$ stabilizes after finitely many steps.

That being the case, eventually there will be an $n$ such that $x^n\in x^{n+1}R$, so that $x^n=x^{n+1}y$ for some $y\in R$. If $x$ isn't a zero divisor, you can repeatedly cancel it off the left until $1=xy$. Thus $x$ is a unit.